# Meteor-Down: Cant assign new instance to mdown variable - undefined is not a function

Tags: function, variables, meteor, undefined, telescope

I try to include meteor down into my application like the telescope example:
https://gist.github.com/mnmtanish/fe4f7efb3db24e83c310

```
var mdown = new MeteorDown(function(error, client){
    //code block
});
```

My console tells me:
    `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`

`meteor list
 meteorhacks:meteor-down      1.1.1  Load Testing Framework for Meteor`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like shortly after that gist was posted the API had changed. If you look at this commit: https://github.com/meteorhacks/meteor-down/commit/7791be3a912f37c5a7cf82a230344fb1f761edcd

```
-      var mdown = new MeteorDown(function (error, client) {
-      client.call('add', x, y, function (err, res) {
```

was removed. It looks like meteorDown is now what you want to use. I would suggest looking through the Meteor Down documentation for the latest usage of the API

Specifically the Readme shows the new way to handle this below:

```
meteorDown.init(function (Meteor) {
    Meteor.call('example-method', function (error, result) {
    Meteor.kill();
  });
});

meteorDown.run({
  concurrency: 10,
  url: "http://localhost:3000"
});
```

Comment: this code works fine so far if it is in a sperated .js file to start it with the shell: `meteor-down my_load_test.js`
I am looking to include it into the client.js so I can start the script with a button for example.

Comment: `var mdown = new meteorDown(function(error, client){
    //code block
});` results:
`Uncaught ReferenceError: meteorDown is not defined`